# SQLite database won't get pushed to phone during testing

Tags: android, sqlite

I have my sqlite db in my assets folder.  The db is called foo.db   When I go to test my app, either on the emulator or my device, it always says no db present, created blank db.  My db is loaded with data and I want to have it push to the phone or emulator for testing.  Why does this not work?

Below is the section of my app that checks to see if the database is there... but it never finds it.  I have run it in debug mode and the DB_PATH  and DB_NAME have correct values, but still it creates an empty database each time.

What am I overlooking?

```
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listpage);
    this.myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        //do nothing - database already exist
        System.out.println("DB alrady exists  comment this out before your deply");
    } else {
        System.out.println("an empty DB is beng created  comment this out before your deply");
        //By calling this method an empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the
 * application.
 *
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        //database does't exist yet.
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: How are you accessing this? By "Assets\<DBname>" or by doing private static String DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/data/my_package_name/databases/";

Comment: Context.getFilesDir().getPath() + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
    + "/databases/"; is this the path?